# Copy to the next available line with my code

Tags: excel, vba

With the code I am currently using it will paste the information from Worksheet 1 to worksheet 2 in the Top line of worksheet2. What I want next is to use the same code but for different cell values and to copy the information from worksheet 1 to worksheet 2 but in the next available line in worksheet 2.

I have been researching about excel macros and vba for a while now and I am still having trouble. I have worked on not using select and activate within my excel code but I am still having trouble with my code now. I am trying to automate my excel workbook as much as I can for easier use.

```
Sub Copy()

Dim Cell As Range
Dim myRow As Long

myRow = 1
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    For Each Cell In .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)  
        If Cell.Value = "Tuck Chow" And Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "OPT" Then
            .Rows(Cell.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(myRow)
            myRow = myRow + 1
        End If
     Next Cell
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `myRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRow1 As Long, LastRow2 As Long, i As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To LastRow1

            If .Range("A" & i).Value = "Tuck Chow" And .Range("B" & i).Value = "OPT" Then

                LastRow2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

                .Rows(i).Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows(LastRow2 + 1)

            End If

         Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @TJunky glad yo hear that codes works. In order to helps others with similar question vote as the correct answer please

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
Sub Copy()

Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Dim newRow As Long

'setting sheets
Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

With sh1
    For Each cel In .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        If cel.Value = "Tuck Chow" And cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = "OPT" Then
            'getting new row on Sheet2
            If sh2.Cells(1, 1) = "" Then
                newRow = 1
            Else
                newRow = sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            End If
            'copying
            cel.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=sh2.Cells(newRow, 1)
        End If
    Next cel
End With

'deselecting row
sh2.Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```